# How to set the "SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml" to be a link with white color

Tags: master-page, page-layout, custom-masterpage, branding

I wrote the following to update my SP web application branding :-

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://****:26611/
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = '<div class="ms-core-brandingText"> <a class="ms-core-brandingText" href="/" >Wp</a></div>'
$webApp.Update()
```

but the result was not very pleasant, because i though the branding link will be while colored , but seems it will get a blue or visited color as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce how to define my branding link to always be white colored ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty version (no external CSS file)

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://****:26611/
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = '<div class="ms-core-brandingText"> <a class="ms-core-brandingText" style="color:white" href="/" >Wp</a></div>'
$webApp.Update()
```

Might need an `!important`, I'm not connected to a farm to try it out right now

Comment: this worked well, but i was trying to avoid manually force the color to be white, as i wanted to comply with what ever SP provide for the  ms-core-brandingText ..

Comment: If you need that you need to add your own CSS file (as alternate CSS or by for example a custom action or delegate control, tons of example of this on this site and on the web). Then in that file you need to apply the same branding as above to the element